# Firebase Notification: send notifications to multiple topic using FCM

Tags: javascript, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I successfully set FCM in my Website and it is working perfectly. I am using JavaScript to send notification. when I send a conditional notification based on a topic. e.g.

```
var topic = "('movies' in topics || 'movies' in topics)";
admin.messaging().sendToCondition(topic, payload,options)
    .then(function(err, response) {
      if(err){
          console.log("Error : ", err.results);
      }
      console.log("Successfully sent message:", err);
})
```

But when I change the condition to

```
var topic = "('movies' in topics || 'IND' in topics)";
```

the client didn't receive any notification even though notification sent successfully.

PS: client has subscribed to movies and it works completely fine but not working on using conditions.

Comment: did you solve this issue? am experiencing the same thing now (js)

Comment: No I was not able to solve it